# How to use Getter setters in array

Tags: c#, arrays, oop, setter, getter

I have been using the c++ and new in c#. In c++ i use `int a[8]` to declare an array and if the array is of an object we set the value by `item[0].SetID(5)` which will set the value of first item's ID to 5. But i m unable to do it in c#.

```
namespace Arrays
{
    class items {
        public int ID { set; get; }
        public string name { set; get; }
        public items(int ID) {
            this.ID = ID;
            name = "Faizan";
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var i=new items[4];
            i[0].ID=6;// this line is kind of c++ code but how I do it in c#
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                i[k] = new items(r.Next());
            }
            foreach(items it in i){
                Console.WriteLine("The item name {0} and the Id is {1}",it.name,it.ID);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your array will be full of null elements. You need to instantiate the object in int[0]

Comment: A suggestion unrelated to your question: You might consider calling you class "item" rather than "items". This would be better because the class appears to model a single item rather than a collection of items. A small point, but it'll make your code more readable to anyone who isn't intimately familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

Array will be filled with default values after creating. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If you do not initialize an array at the time of declaration, the
>   array members are automatically initialized to the default initial
>   value for the array type.

For reference types (i.e. classes) default values are nulls. So you should initialize array items **before** accessing them:

```
var i =new items[4];
// i[0] here is null

for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
     i[k] = new items(r.Next()); // now i[0] points to object in memory
}

i[0].ID = 6;// now you can set object's property
```

Answer (score 1):

Your item at index 0 is null. You need to do this instead

```
i[0] = new items{ID = 6};
```

Comment: you have to use "new":

Answer (score 0):

> i[0].ID=6;// this line is kind of c++ code but how I do it in c#

Your array at tha point is *empty*. You initialize it after in loop.

So

- first initialize array with values
- after access/changes properties of the instances inside that array

  ```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {

      Random r = new Random();
      for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
          i[k] = new items(r.Next());
      }
      foreach(items it in i){
          Console.WriteLine("The item name {0} and the Id is {1}",it.name,it.ID);
      }

      var i= items[4];
      i.ID=6;// NOW YOU CAN ACCCESS IT

      //OR SIMPLY 
      items[4].ID=6;

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

IN c++ when we declare the array of an object it is automatically initialize to NULL or "0" and we can get or set the value just after that(correct me if i am wrong). What about the c#?
What i think is that var i=new items[4]; this line initializes the array as well,does it?